# How to order by cumulative value?

Tags: postgresql, query, cte, window-functions

In my application widgets move step by step through a workflow.  I want to list the widgets ordered by their step due-dates but I can't figure out how to do that.

There are many workflows.  Each workflow has a number of steps ordered by integer `position`.  Each step has an integer `duration` for the number of days it should take.

A widget has a start date and points to its current step in a workflow.  To calculate a step's due date, I add up the durations of the steps (in the same workflow) which preceded it, add on the step's own duration, and add the total to the widget's start date.

I can't figure out how to express this in SQL.  I suspect window functions or common table expressions are involved but I don't have any experience with them.

The simplified tables look like:

```
workflows: id

steps: id, workflow_id, position, duration

widgets: id, start_date, step_id
```

Conceptually for each widget I want to calculate the cumulative duration for its step in the step's workflow and add that to the widget's start date.

To just calculate the cumulative duration for each step I can do this:

```sql
WITH f AS (
  SELECT p.id, sum(q.duration) AS tot
  FROM steps p
  INNER JOIN steps q
  ON p.workflow_id=q.workflow_id AND q.position<=p.position
  GROUP BY p.id
)
SELECT w.id, w.step_id, f.tot
FROM widgets w
INNER JOIN f
ON f.id=w.step_id;
```

I just need to figure out how to add these total durations to the start dates and order by them.

Update: here a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/aeOpfEwT

Comment: A fiddle (showing exact table definition, some sample rows, and the desired result) would invite more answers. Random example: https://dbfiddle.uk/Se6hcwSs

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thank you.  I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suspect window functions or common table expressions ...

You were on the right track, but took the wrong turn. The feature you are looking for is a [**window function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT w.id, w.step_id, s.tot, w.created_at + s.tot * interval '1 day' AS step_due
FROM   widgets w
JOIN  (
   SELECT id
        , sum(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY workflow_id ORDER BY position) AS tot
   FROM   steps
   ) s ON s.id = w.step_id
ORDER  BY step_due;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uKH3O9Lt)

(You cold also involve a CTE, but that's not required for the task.)

Since `created_at` happens to be a `date`, and `duration` is an `integer` (as revealed by your update), you can simplify to:

```
... w.created_at + s.tot::int AS step_due
```

... and get an actual `date` as result, instead of a `timestamp` like you do now.
The cast to integer (`::int`) is necessary because `sum(int)` produces `bigint`, and we need `date + int` for this to work. See:

- [Date arithmetic on values of type DATE without resulting in TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742129/939860)

#### "Window frame"

`PARTITION BY` partitions the underlying set into strictly separated partitions (after applying `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` if given).

`ORDER BY` does not exactly introduce a window frame. It defines a sort order with bearing on the effective window frame. The frame itself is set by the "frame clause".

Without `ORDER BY`, all rows within each partition are peers with no particular order. And with the default frame clause of `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` the whole partition is the window frame.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

> The `PARTITION BY` clause groups the rows of the query into
> partitions, which are processed separately by the window function.
> `PARTITION BY` works similarly to a query-level `GROUP BY` clause,
> except that its expressions are always just expressions and cannot be
> output-column names or numbers. Without `PARTITION BY`, all rows
> produced by the query are treated as a single partition. The `ORDER BY` clause determines the order in which the rows of a partition are
> processed by the window function. It works similarly to a query-level
> `ORDER BY` clause, but likewise cannot use output-column names or
> numbers. Without `ORDER BY`, rows are processed in an unspecified
> order.
>
> The ***`frame_clause`*** specifies the set of rows constituting the
> window frame, which is a subset of the current partition, for those
> window functions that act on the frame instead of the whole partition.
> The set of rows in the frame can vary depending on which row is the
> current row. The frame can be specified in `RANGE`, `ROWS` or `GROUPS`
> mode; in each case, it runs from the frame_start to the frame_end. If
> frame_end is omitted, the end defaults to `CURRENT ROW`.

And:

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is
> the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With
> `ORDER BY`, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition
> start up through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer. Without
> `ORDER BY`, this means all rows of the partition are included in the
> window frame, since all rows become peers of the current row.

There is more, read the whole chapter for clarity.

`RANGE` is the default mode according to the (unfortunate) SQL standard. `ROWS` is more intuitive in most cases and actually faster, too. This insight allows for performance optimization - which hardly anybody seems to realize. So this should actually be a bit faster:

```
...
        , sum(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY workflow_id ORDER BY position
                              ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS tot
...
```

Related:

- [Find first 3 orders for each customer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72824267/939860)

While there are no peers (deterministic sort order within partitions) both framing modes do effectively the same, and you can safely replace `RANGE` with `ROWS` for simple cases.

Comment: As far as I can tell your window function doesn't exclude steps with a position greater than the current step's position.

Comment: Thanks for the info re `s.tot::int AS step_due`.  I'll make a fiddle now.

Comment: Just added a dbfiddle to my question.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your query in the dbfiddle and of course it works.  However I don't understand how the partition excludes steps with a higher position.

Comment: Aha, the ORDER BY introduces a window frame.  I did not know about this - thank you!

Comment: @AndyStewart, as you noted ORDER BY introduces a window frame. If you don't specify what it should be, the default frame is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Comment: @Lennart I added a chapter addressing the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```sql
WITH f AS (
  SELECT p.id, sum(q.duration) AS tot
  FROM steps p
  INNER JOIN steps q
  ON p.workflow_id=q.workflow_id AND q.position<=p.position
  GROUP BY p.id
)
SELECT w.id, w.step_id, f.tot, w.created_at + f.tot * INTERVAL '1 day' AS step_due
FROM widgets w
INNER JOIN f
ON f.id=w.step_id
ORDER BY step_due;
```